# Python cant import ucimlrepo library

Tags: python, database

I can't import python ucimlrepo library

```
from ucimlrepo import fetch_ucirepo

# fetch dataset
iris = fetch_ucirepo(id=53)

# data (as pandas dataframes)
X = iris.data.features
y = iris.data.targets

# metadata
print(iris.metadata)

# variable information
print(iris.variables)
```

I installed ucimlrepo, panda and pandas with pip install command and it was successfully.
This is my path:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by setting environment from Virtual to System in Pycharm.